# Not able to get data in the dataFilter function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter the json array received from the server. I'm able to receive the data properly in the success function however I get a "data is undefined error" within the filterdata block. [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined]

```
$(function () {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }

            $("#city").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?mode=json&type=like",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            q: request.term
                        },

                        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
                            console.log(data);

                            alert(data.list.length);
                            alert(data.list[0].name + ', ' + data.list[0].sys.country);
                            jsonObj = [];
                            for (i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
                                item = {}
                                item["city"] = data.list[0].name;
                                item["country"] = data.list[0].sys.country;
                                jsonObj.push(item);
                            }
                            return jsonObj;

                        },

                        success: function (data) {
                            //alert(data.list.length);
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });                 
                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    log(ui.item ?
                      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try `success` Instead of `dataFilter`, and show the some of your back-end code, Plus check console and see what have you received in response.

Comment: use `console.log(data);` in success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [dataFilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is a function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest. Since you are using JSONP request, which is not an XHR request so there is no XHR object and no raw data, which makes the behavior of dataFilter in your case perfectly valid. You should check the response in success callback instead.